# I facing an issue with robot.txt file

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

I am using WordPress. Google not crawl all resource of my page. it shows "**Page partially loaded**". I had all ready tried too many times to solve this issue with `robots.txt` file. My website return bad gateway error.

**Here's screenshot**

[image]

My website link : [https://www.alphaclick.in](http://www.alphaclick.in)

**My robots.txt File**

```
User-agent:  *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/

Disallow: /wp-admin/

Disallow: /linkout/

Disallow: /recommended/

Disallow: /comments/feed/

Disallow: /trackback/

Disallow: /index.php

Disallow: /xmlrpc.php

User-agent: NinjaBot
Allow: /

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*

Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image

Allow: /wp-content/uploads/

User-agent: Adsbot-Google

Allow: /


User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile

Allow: /

Sitemap: https://www.alphaclick.in/sitemap_index.xml
Sitemap: https://www.alphaclick.in/post-sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this line `Disallow: /index.php`. It's blocking the whole website for bots. More information about `robots.txt` file you can get [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596)